# Where and When GC_CONCURRENT invoke?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, dalvik

I found the source code of dalvikvm, but could not find where the concurrent GC invoke.

The malloc code I got from the android git repository

```
static void gcForMalloc(bool clearSoftReferences)
{
    if (gDvm.allocProf.enabled) {
        Thread* self = dvmThreadSelf();
        gDvm.allocProf.gcCount++;
        if (self != NULL) {
            self->allocProf.gcCount++;
        }
    }
    /* This may adjust the soft limit as a side-effect.
     */
    const GcSpec *spec = clearSoftReferences ? GC_BEFORE_OOM : GC_FOR_MALLOC;
    dvmCollectGarbageInternal(spec);
}
```

I think the dvmCollectGarbageInternal function prinft the GC LOG, but there is nothing about the GC_CONCURRENT.

The dvmCollectGarbageInternal function's log code

```
if (!spec->isConcurrent) {
    u4 markSweepTime = dirtyEnd - rootStart;
    u4 gcTime = gcEnd - rootStart;
    bool isSmall = numBytesFreed > 0 && numBytesFreed < 1024;
    ALOGD("%s freed %s%zdK, %d%% free %zdK/%zdK, paused %ums, total %ums",
         spec->reason,
         isSmall ? "<" : "",
         numBytesFreed ? MAX(numBytesFreed / 1024, 1) : 0,
         percentFree,
         currAllocated / 1024, currFootprint / 1024,
         markSweepTime, gcTime);
} else {
    u4 rootTime = rootEnd - rootStart;
    u4 dirtyTime = dirtyEnd - dirtyStart;
    u4 gcTime = gcEnd - rootStart;
    bool isSmall = numBytesFreed > 0 && numBytesFreed < 1024;
    ALOGD("%s freed %s%zdK, %d%% free %zdK/%zdK, paused %ums+%ums, total %ums",
         spec->reason,
         isSmall ? "<" : "",
         numBytesFreed ? MAX(numBytesFreed / 1024, 1) : 0,
         percentFree,
         currAllocated / 1024, currFootprint / 1024,
         rootTime, dirtyTime, gcTime);
}
```

The above code is from master branch of Android, and my nexus phone's Android version is 4.4.2.
  Do I miss something?

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GC_CONCURRENT`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/dalvik/vm/alloc/Heap.cpp#56) is invoked in [`gcDaemonThread()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/dalvik/vm/alloc/HeapSource.cpp#486).

Comment: That's the first piece of the puzzle.  `gcDaemonThread()` wakes up when signaled...